# Why client.post in Django keeps returns GET response

Tags: django, testing

I'm developing web apps under django 2.0.4 and python 3. And I need to write a test for the Signup view, to make sure that the redirection happens after a successful signup is made. Here is the code:

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.cotnrib.auth.models import User
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .form import SignupForm

class SignupView(View):
    template_name='signup/signup.html'
    form_class = SignupForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form })

    post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user=authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            if user is Not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = self.form_class()
            context = {'form' : form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form})
```

urls.py (app)

```
from django.url import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    ...
]
```

signup.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
```

All above works well, until I try to make a test on the post. That is a test against the code.

```
return redirect('index')
```

Here is the test code in "test_views.py"

```
class SignUpViewTest(TestCase):
    def test_view_redirect_after_post(self):
      post_data = {'username': 'mary',
                 'first_name':'Mary',
                 'last_name': 'Farh',
                 'password1': '1234_abcd',
                 'password2':'1234_abcd',
                 'email': 'goinhome@outlook.com'}
      resp = self.client.post(reverse('signup'), post_data)
      #self.assertRedircts(resp, reverse('index'))
      self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)
```

I ALWASYS get resp.status_code as 200. And I am quite sure that the HttpResponse comes from "else" clause (in views.py).

```
class SignupView(View)
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
        else:
            form = self.form_class()
            context = {'form' : form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form})
```

Please tell me why the branch

```
if  form.is_valid():
    ...
```

is bypassed. And tell me how to fix my test.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not bypassed, it's doing exactly what it is supposed to: your form is not valid. You'll need to look at the contents of form.errors to find out why.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, can you tell me which data to be posted is in valid. I've checked many times, and cannot find it. The test data to be posted has been published above

Comment: I don't know, because you overwrite the bound form with a new non-bound version in your else block, so there is no way to tell. Remove that and then examine `resp.context['form'].errors`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried your approach.        resp = self.client.post(reverse('signup'), post_data);
        print('form errors %s' % (resp.context['form'].errors));  self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302); And run the test. The res.context['form'].errors is None

Comment: Did you delete the `form = self.form_class()` line in your view?

Comment: Thank you very much, now that the resp.context['form'].errors complain that the password is too common. I think you solved my problem. Thank you again!